# Why are my scroll bars so wacky looking?

Tags: unity, themes

I'm not sure what I did, but my scroll bars look like hell. In this picture, you can see them adjacent to the suggested questions and at the windows edge. What is that about?

[image: Scroll bars being wacky]

This behavior is consistent across all applications -- at the top and bottom of any scroll bar, I see a tall grey box. And in some cases I get this wacky multiple horizontal scroll:

[image: freaky horizontal scroll]

In trying to fix this, I managed to totally trash my compiz settings ([What do I do about my busted GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372488/what-do-i-do-about-my-busted-gui#372490)) so now I've restored Compiz to its default settings and the scrollbars are still totally crazy looking.

Comment: @vasa1 Updated the Q -- it happens everywhere.

Comment: Huh. I don't remember changing my theme, but indeed. That made a difference. @Braiam If you make it an answer I can accept it. Resetting Compiz seemed to resolve the issue in other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be your theme. You should be able to switch back and forth themes. If you find that your theme wasn't the one you selected, change it back. If you find that some theme is indeed problematic, file a bug.

Comment: I think I had more than one problem going on. Resetting Compiz resolved the problem everywhere but Firefox. Reverting to Firefox's default theme solved the problem in Firefox.