# What do I do about my busted GUI?

Tags: unity, compiz, 13.10

I have been trying to dial down Compiz's stranglehold on my memory, and not keeping very good notes. I think all I did was reduce the texture quality in OpenGL, per [Roland Taylor's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82684/how-to-lower-compiz-memory-usage/82698#82698). But I did something that left my [scrollbars looking totally wonky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372331/why-are-my-scroll-bars-so-wacky-looking?noredirect=1#comment475950_372331). I tried to undo that by resetting Compiz to its default settings and now I have wonky looking scroll bars, I can't drag windows around, my windows have no decoration and I can't switch between applications except by pointing and clicking.

As it happens I have a terminal open and visible, and this browser window, but that's it. I was reading instructions on [How can I reset compiz to the default settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36163/how-can-i-reset-compiz-to-the-default-settings) and `unity --reset` doesn't work in 13.10 ("ERROR: the reset option is now depricated")

How do I restore compiz's defaults in 13.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  To reset Compiz and Unity to defaults. just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
unity --reset-icons
```

Also you can try this:
Run Compiz, and and click on reset to defaults.  If that doesn't help, create a new profile, and then click on reset to defaults

[image]

Comment: I got as far as `setsid unity` which had the effect of killing /hiding that terminal (I can't drag windows so I can't tell if it is just hiding somewhere). Even ctrl-alt-t isn't working.

Comment: I just edited the answer, see if it works now.

Comment: I had dconf-tools. I can launch a ccsm gui, is there a way to reset to defaults from there?

Comment: Yup. I just figured that out. I had to also re-enable the Unity Plugin for some reason.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)